# How does :root :nth-child(1) target the first heading

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Does anyone know why the following code sets the style for the tag `<h1>` I do not understand why this is happening, I have never set the style for the tag `<head>` before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
              :root {
            background: green;
        }

            :root :nth-child(1) {
                text-decoration: underline;
                color:white;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <h2>Header</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that if you were to remove the descendant selector such that you have `:root:nth-child(1)`, nothing will be matched. This is because the root element doesn't have a parent. It is notably the only element that will *never* match `:nth-child(n)` in a non-shadow DOM, which is a guaranteed match for all other non-shadow elements.

Answer (score 2):

It works because you've set all the first-children (`:first-child`/`:nth-child(1)`) elements, contained within the `:root` element (all elements are within that `:root` element) to have that style.

> I have never set the style for the tag "head" before.

You still haven't, you've merely contained, or placed, the `<style />` element *within* the `<head>`.

Answer (score 2):

[`:nth-child(1)`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#nth-child-pseudo) matches all the **first child** elements of their parents which are descendants of the `:root` element<sup>1</sup>. Therefore the first heading `<h1>` element within the `<body>` would be selected, whether you have used [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) or not.

Considering the given markup, the `<head>` and the `<h1>` would be the subject of `:nth-child(1)` or `:root :nth-child(1)` selectors since they are the first child of their parents, `<html>` and the `<body>`

---

<sup>1. In HTML the root element is `<html>`</sup>